# Dell Inspiron HDMI not working

Tags: nvidia, dell, hdmi, inspiron

My Machine is a Dell make and the model is Inspiron-N5110 
It has a Nvidia 540M graphics card in it.
I cannot connect my laptop to the TV via HDMI and i tried installing bumblebee, nvidia-current, but no success so far.

Any one with the same issues, please help

Answer (score 1):

Try http://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Multi-monitor-setup 
It has steps to enable more monitors, I have not tried it.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, both in Windows and Ubuntu 18.04. I solved it by diagnosing my machine specs, downloading and installing the newest drivers at Dell Support:

https://www.dell.com/support/home/br/pt/brbsdt1?~ck=mn

After that, I changed the BIOS settings removing Legacy mode, enabling secure boot and UEFI.